# How static modifier works?

Tags: c#, static

Suppose I have a static property like the following:

```
public static object MyProperty
{
   get { return new object(); }
}
```

Is the above property the same of?

```
private static object my_filed = new object();

public static object MyProperty
{
   get { return my_filed; }
}
```

I.e: Is the new object created each time I call my static property or only the first time?

Comment: While it's a good question, you could easily experiment and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property getter is executed every time the property is read, so it will create a new object instance every time.

Answer (score 2):

Two mechanisms are different. In first one, it will create new object every time.

Though `Static methods/variables` are associated with class definition but the code written inside the static method gets executed whenever the method is called. In your example, you have written statement to create new object instance so **it will create a new object instance whenever the method is called.**

Answer (score 2):

No it's not.

```
public static object MyProperty
{
   get { return new object(); }
}
```

will return each time a new instance of the object, which is probably not what you want, and

```
private static object my_filed = new object();

public static object MyProperty
{
   get { return my_filed; }
}
```

will return each time the same instance of the class object, making it a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

A static property is similar to a static method. It uses the composite name to be accessed. Static properties use the same get and set tokens as instance properties. In your program, first case will create new object every time. Second not.

Answer (score 1):

To know the correct answer you need to know what properties are. Properties are nothing other than a method which is hidden from you.

So `var myVar = MyClass.MyProperty` is nothing else than `var myVar = MyClass.get_MyProperty()`. So when you calling:

```
public static Object MyProperty
{
    get { return new Object(); }
}
```

You are calling a method which creates a new Object each time. So the answer is no, the code isn't the same. [The static modifier does something else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx).